# Blank when NaN in jqGrid cells

Tags: jqgrid, cell, nan

How to set blank instead of NaN in jqGrid cells ? Using formatter ? Is there an example?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: +1 to the above. raouf - Can you provide more information about your problem? Some code samples would probably help as well.

Comment: Thank you Justin! Displaying database numeric data on jqgrid with formatter:'currency' in colmodel works fine for not DBNull values. But when value is DBNull the word 'NaN' appears in jqgrid cell. the question is : How to do avoid 'NaN' and put a blank (space) instead.

Comment: take a look at [this post][1], it should answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024027/jqgrid-show-blank-instead-of-null

Answer (score 6):

This is REALLY old but the jqGrid documentation didn't have an easy answer and this question pulls up first in Google results when I was looking for the same answer.

I was able to display a blank cell instead of a 0 when using the predefined formatter option for an integer using this code:

```
{ name: 'Quantity', formatter: 'integer', formatoptions: { defaultValue: ''} }
```

The `defaultValue` is just set to blank.

Comment: Thank God that there was someone to ansawer "really" old question :). You saved my day even3 years later.

Comment: Add one more to the grateful group. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not rewrite the custom formatter -- but override it (or make a new one)! That way, when a new version of jQgrid comes out, you don't overwrite your custom wrapper.

For example, my users don't want to see the value if it is 0, so I do this:

```
$.fn.fmatter.currency = function (cellval, opts) {
    if (cellval == 0) {
        return '';
    }
    var op = $.extend({},opts.currency);
    if(!isUndefined(opts.colModel.formatoptions)) {
        op = $.extend({},op,opts.colModel.formatoptions);
    }
    if(isEmpty(cellval)) {
        return op.defaultValue;
    }
    return $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(cellval,op);
};
```

But I could also call it:

```
$.fn.fmatter.currencyNoZero
```

In your case, I would do this:

```
$.fn.fmatter.currency = function (cellval, opts) {
    if (cellval == null) {
        return '';
    }
    var op = $.extend({},opts.currency);
    if(!isUndefined(opts.colModel.formatoptions)) {
        op = $.extend({},op,opts.colModel.formatoptions);
    }
    if(isEmpty(cellval)) {
        return op.defaultValue;
    }
    return $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(cellval,op);
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest to combine both, i.e. `if (cellval == 0 || cellval == null) { return ''; }`

Answer (score 0):

On the server, before you return your data as XML/JSON/whatever, try setting DBNull values equal to a blank string.

Alternatively, if it is acceptable to display NULL values as 0, you could modify your SQL along these lines:

```
SELECT IsNull(my_amount, 0)
```

Comment: I think that the solution is in the formatter option of colmodel. There are two ways: Predefined and Custom formatter. In my case, i want to use the predefined 'currency' formatter, but with the possibility to return blank instead of 'NaN' when value is null. It seems that there is no way to avoid rewriting my custum currency formatter function.Thank you again Justin.