# Handling "undefined" JSON values in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

In my JSON, sometimes I don't return a value for a column -- I simply omit that column from the JSON.  In this case, I would like these cells in the grid to be empty.

However, this causes display issues in jqGrid.  The values of these cells become `undefined`.

Is there a solution to this other than adding the empty columns to the JSON as empty strings or creating a formatter function in the `colModel` that checks for `undefined`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with the formatter solution to change `undefined` to `''`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775776/blank-when-nan-in-jqgrid-cells

Comment: Agree with @js1568 - go with the formatter

Comment: The problem with a formatter is that it must be used on every column.  I have up to 30 columns!