# jqGrid: Null Custom Formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, null

I would like to replace blank values in the grid with 'NULL'. I've read that null values in the data are displayed as empty cells by default in jqGrid. As per a special request I need to have those blank values formatted to read as 'NULL'.

I found this relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024027/jqgrid-show-blank-instead-of-null) that is trying to do the opposite--replace 'NULL' with blank values. I used that code to set the cellvalue to 'NULL' instead of ' ' if the cell value is either undefined or isNull. But when I run the code the grid never loads. I just get the "loading..." message box and it never loads any data.

Below is the code I used:

```
var nullFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if(cellvalue === undefined || isNull(cellvalue)) {
        cellvalue = 'NULL';
    }
    return cellvalue;
}


$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ....
    colModel: [{
        label: 'Name',
        name:'name',
        index:'name',
        formatter:nullFormatter
    }, {
        label: 'Next Column',
        name:'nextCol',
        index:'nextCol',
        formatter: nullFormatter
    }, ...],
    ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include some **test data** which you use to fill the grid?  Are there difference between `null` and empty string `""` in the data?Which `datatype` you use (`"local"`, `"json"` etc)?

Comment: Hi Oleg, my test data fields are set to null but display blanks in PHPmyadmin. I am using json datatype.

Answer (score 0):

When jQGrid receives a `null` value for one of its cells, it actually places the HTML entity: `&nbsp;` in the cell.

So, here is what your updated custom formatter function should look like:

```
var nullFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    // if cellvalue is &nbsp; OR a single space
    if(cellvalue == "&nbsp;" || cellvalue == " ") {
        cellvalue = 'NULL';
    }
    return cellvalue;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply to my question! Thank you for the jqGrid insight. I didn't know that the grid places the HTML code &nbsp; in the cells that are NULL. I tried your code suggestion and it loads the data but doesn't format any of the blank values as 'NULL' in the grid.

Comment: @klm10 I recently updated my answer - please check for both `&nbsp;` and for `" "` (a single space) in your `if` statement. Does this help at all?

Comment: I copied over your updated code segment and it still doesn't format the blanks to display as 'NULL'. I appreciate your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

You colud try adding a condition in your if to check if the value is equal to "null" as if it is a string like this:

```
var nullFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if(cellvalue === undefined || isNull(cellvalue) || cellvalue == 'null') {
        cellvalue = 'NULL';
    }
    return cellvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code . Its Working.. .It seems that "isNull(cellvalue)" function is not working .Instead of this
 var nullFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {},
 Try function nullFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

```js
  function nullFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        if (cellvalue === undefined || cellvalue === 'null' || cellvalue === 'NULL' || cellvalue === null) {
            cellvalue = '-';
        }

        return cellvalue;
    }
    
    
   colModel:[ { name: 'taskStatus', index: 'taskStatus', template: gridTextareaTemplate, formatter: nullFormatter }]
```