# jqGrid shows NULL data as "undefined"

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Having trouble with data coming from the server as nulls...in the jqGrid they show as "undefined".

My data source is server side XML, and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
  <row id="0">
    <cell><![CDATA[0]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[MENUBAR]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[Main Menu]]></cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell><![CDATA[Y]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[1]]></cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell><![CDATA[1]]></cell>
  </row>
  <row id="1">
    <cell><![CDATA[1]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[PCHN_MGT]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[Channel Maanagement]]></cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell><![CDATA[Y]]></cell>
    <cell><![CDATA[1]]></cell>
    <cell/>
    <cell/>
    <cell><![CDATA[2]]></cell>
  </row>
```

Note the empty cell values, these are the NULLs.

Here is my jqGrid setup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
// Grid
$(function(){ 
  $("#list1").jqGrid({ 
    url:'!wspitm.P_PITM_LIST_XOUT',
    datatype: 'xml',
    editurl: "!wspitm.P_PITM_LIST_POST",
    gridview: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    prmNames: {page:"page", rows:"rows", sort: "sidx", order: "sord", search:"isearch", nd:"nd", id:"id", oper:"oper", editoper:"edit", addoper:"add", deloper:"del", subgridid:"id", npage: null, totalrows:"totalrows"},
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,50],
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Portal Item List',
    sortorder: "asc",
    width: "1100",
    height: "250",
    sortname: "WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID",
colModel:[ 
{
name:"WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID", 
align:"left", 
index:"WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID", 
editable: false, 
edittype: "text", 
editrules: { required: false, edithidden: true }, 
formoptions: { label: "ID" }, 
formatter: "", 
label:"ID", 
sortable: true, 
width:15, 
classes: "" 
}
 ,
{
name:"WWBPITM_TITLE", 
align:"left", 
index:"WWBPITM_TITLE", 
editable: true, 
edittype: "text", 
editoptions: { size: 255 }, 
editrules: { required: true }, 
formoptions: { label: "Title" }, 
formatter: "", 
label:"Title", 
sortable: true, 
width:50, 
classes: "" 
}
 ,
{
name:"WWBPITM_SUBTITLE", 
align:"left", 
index:"WWBPITM_SUBTITLE", 
hidden: true, 
editable: true, 
edittype: "text", 
editoptions: { size: 255 }, 
editrules: { required: false }, 
formoptions: { label: "Sub-Title" }, 
formatter: "", 
label:"Sub-Title", 
sortable: true, 
width:75, 
classes: "" 
}

etc. etc.
```

I tried using a custom formatter to convert undefined to "" (like this [JQGRID show blank instead of Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024027/jqgrid-show-blank-instead-of-null)) but that isn't working either.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code, but I can't reproduce the problem. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Bean.htm). **I would strictly recommend you to remove `formatter: ""`**. It produces exception on building of every cell content, but the displayed results are still OK. It's very bad to include the values of different possible properties in `colModel`. It makes not only the code bad readable, but it could be origin of different errors. The column definition

```js
{
    name:"WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID", 
    align:"left", 
    index:"WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID", 
    editable: false, 
    edittype: "text", 
    editrules: { required: false, edithidden: true }, 
    formoptions: { label: "ID" }, 
    formatter: "", 
    label:"ID", 
    sortable: true, 
    width:15, 
    classes: "" 
}
```

can (and should) be reduced to the following

```js
{
    name: "WWBPITM_SURROGATE_ID",
    label: "ID",
    width: 15
}
```

Comment: I removed the empty classes too. All the rest I see as valid, and although it may seem harder to read it is actually easier for us, and I must ask why you say "should" be reduced. To us, it is more clear when we are explicit with how the columns are defined. example: do you really expect that our developers are going to remember that the default for align is left? No...it's better that they are explicit. 

I also suggest that the parsing routine skip/ignore empty values rather than error out...unless "empty" actually means something...